# Which Linux directory should I be building my NodeJS / Express projects?

Tags: linux, node.js

A super Linux noob question.

I want to learn and develop some NodeJS/Express applications on a VM running a Bitnami Node Stack on an Ubuntu build.

But I am a little confused as to which folder would be considered best practice for me to build out of.

There appears to be an Opt directory which contains a Bitnami directory which then has a nodejs, apache2, git, redis and scripts sub directories.

There is also a Home directory which has a Bitnami directory (which is empty).

Where do most developers in Linux choose to build their apps?

Comment: building is a user operation so it should be done from your home (which hopefully is on another partition). Convention says that the built output for local software should be placed in /opt when you deploy it to a system to be used, but only then. If you are deploying as web project, then follow the conventions for the server type you are using (usually /var).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Thomas is correct.  Since building is a user operation it can go into a directory somewhere off of your home folder.  When deployed typically it would go into /opt.  The only thing I wanted to add to his answer was this link showing what all the directories are typically used for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#Conventional_directory_layout